# Registrar la entrada y validar la salida (PHP SQL SERVER)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php8

Estoy creando una aplicación de marcaciones de entradas y salidas de empleados.
La aplicación al momento de registrar guarda el dato sin problema pero tengo dificultad para validar la salida del empleado el mismo dia.

Esto es lo que intentado;

```
<?php
    require '../controller/config.php';
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_assistance (codentry,date, hr_entry) VALUES (?,getdate(),convert(char(8), getdate(), 108))";
    $params = array($_POST["codentry"]);
// Esto es lo que he intentado 


   // if ($params[0]=="1") {                 

        //Aqui colocas el código que tu deseas realizar cuando el dato existe en la base de datos
       // echo "Record add successfully";
        //}else{
  //$sql = "update tbl_assistance set hr_out = (convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)) where codentry ={$_POST['codentry']}";
    //echo "Salida registrada";
//}   


    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Record add successfully";
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Tambien he intentado con un Trigger en la base de datos que valide si el registro ya existe y agrege el tiempo de salida de acuerdo a su respectivo codentry

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr_hr_out on tbl_assistance 
FOR update
AS
DECLARE
@codigo int
--@hr_salida nvarchar (255)

IF EXISTS (SELECT hr_entry FROM tbl_assistance WHERE codentry = @codigo )
BEGIN
UPDATE tbl_assistance SET hr_out =   convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)

END
```

pero hasta el momento he obtenido lo siguiente por parte del codigo recibo esto por el valor de codentry duplicado
Respuesta del var_dump ;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por base de datos esto;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estructura de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista :

```
<h2 id="HoraActual"> Hora actual</h2>

            <input type="text" name="codentry" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite su codigo" required>
            <br>
 
            <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"><img src="bootstrap5/img/reloj.png" width="40" height="40"> Marcar</button>
```

de que otra manera podría guardar este registro para el campo hr_out?

Comment: Hola, anexa un var_dump de $params, y la estructura de la tabla

Comment: @JoseAntonio ya agregue la información

Comment: la variable post te está llegando null, como la estás pidiendo en la vista? Revisa porque llega null a $params, esto afecta a la consulta

Comment: @JoseAntonio VOY A VALIDARLO AHORA MISMO

Comment: Lo intente, pero sigo sin tener respuesta, lo que hice al momento de validar fue enviarle tambien el parametro dentro del insert , pero se hizo la insercion tambien en este campo, o quizas lo entendi mal ¿Podria inidicarme algun ejemplo? @JoseAntonio

Comment: Coloca el código de la vista también

Comment: @JoseAntonio el codigo de la vista es muy simple

Answer (score 0):

El trigger lo estas invocando al hacer un update no un insert, según yo debería ser mas fácil validar la existencia desde código.

Comment: Comprendo, si solo he intentado las formas que se me han ocurrido, ¿Podrias regalarme un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

En el PHP no guardes lo que te llega por POST en un array, has directamente; `$codentry = $_POST['codentry']`
Entiendo que esta variable que recibes por POST es un identificador de los empleados, es única por empleado.
Entonces para poder hacer un marcado de salida tienes que verificar si ha marcado la entrada, tienes que hacer una consulta a la base de datos:

```
<?php
    require '../controller/config.php';
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $codentry = $_POST["codentry"];

    $entrada = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT hr_entry FROM tbl_assistance WHERE codentry = '{$codentry}' AND date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());");    

    //Si no hay entrada, se registra
    if (!$entrada) {                 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_assistance (codentry,date, hr_entry) VALUES ('{$codentry}', getdate(), convert(char(8), getdate(), 108))";

    //Si marcó la entrada, marca la salida
    }else{
        $sql = "update tbl_assistance set hr_out = (convert(char(8), getdate(), 108)) where codentry = '{$codentry}'";
    }     

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Record add successfully";
    }

    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Con esto quita el trigger y prueba esto, espero te ayude, saludos

Comment: Primeramente, gracias por tomarse el tiempo de mirarlo y hacer las modificaciones necesarias, 
Probe el codigo y los datos se registran muy bien, pero cuando intento realizar la salida, no me lo permite, primero porque el codentry es una llave prima entonces es como si en vez de hacer el update nuevamente le envia el insert, probe quitando las llaves primarias y si se deja , pero lo agrega como un registro mas, pensaba en ponerle un internalo algo asi como "E" y "S"

Comment: ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Bueno, vamos a replantear un poco la resolución. El marcaje que tratas de hacer es una sola entrada y salida por dia. Por lo que la consulta de entrada seria por día. Y hacer la consulta directamente. He modificado mi respuesta, hazlo y me cuentas.

Comment: Estaba probando y haciendo algunos cambios en cuanta a la validacion el IF, es decir, el registro llega e inserta. sin problema, al momento de crear una salida, no esta tomando el update, es decir el IF no lo esta validando por que puse el insert donde esta el update, y el update donde esta el insert y funciona, pero al agregar nuevo registro no lo inserta.

Comment: He hecho una serie de validaciones, pero hasta el momento no logro conseguir que funcione. alguna idea?

Comment: Sube lo que has intentando.